# PostGIS - ST_Collect but only include POLYGONs not POINTs?

Tags: postgis, optimization, union

In PostGSI, is there anyway to turn a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION into a MULTIPOLYGON by dropping all non-POLYGONs/non-MULTIPOLYGONs?

I'm doing a query that cuts a bunch of geometries (using `ST_Intersection`) and I want to group them together. I'm using `ST_Collect` to turn this into a GEOMETRYCOLLECTION. I could use `ST_Union`, but that's slower. Is there an alternative approach where I can drop all the non-POLYGONs/non-MULTIPOLYGONs from a GEOMETRY collection and just return a MULTIPOLYGON?

I know would be less accurate than `ST_Union`, but it should be faster. For what I'm doing a small hit in accuracy is worth it if it speeds it up.

Answer (score 2):

ST_CollectionExtract is what you are looking for:

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_CollectionExtract.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically the st_intersection will generate several types of geometries: polygons, linestring, points.

The problem is that most GIS systems usually use the concept of layers and each layer must be a SET( not a COLLECTION ) of features of same kind.

Sure, just dump the geometry collection into his components and filter those that are not polygons.

You will need the st_dump function in conjuntion with st_geometrytype.

Comment: Are you able to provide a few more details about the steps involved in doing this?  I won't be following them personally but this Answer flagged up for review due to its brevity.